# Sign PDF in Webapp with PKCS #11

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pkcs#11

I need a way to sign a pdf document on a webapp using a private key stored on a Smart Card (PKCS#11).

Until now this kind of problem was solved using a Java Applet, but as chrome phasing out Java this is not a viable solution.

I'm trying to use a pdf viewer plugin to do this (Adobe Acrobat DC should do the work), but I'm not finding anywhere on how to load the pdf and post the signed document.

The process should include loading the signature algorithm and enter the card's PIN.

Does anyone know how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue which I haven't found a holistic solution to the problem. There is a github project which host a [chrome plugin](https://github.com/open-eid/chrome-token-signing) for supporting signing to PDF documents. For Firefox and IE check [here](https://github.com/open-eid/browser-token-signing). In addition they have implemented an [JS API](https://github.com/open-eid/hwcrypto.js) which you can use.

Comment: Please explain more about the links.  An answer should be able to live without relying on external links.